# Recommendations for MCITP Enterprise Server testing

Tags: untagged

Does anyone have any recommendations on study material (books, courses, sites, ect) for the new MCITP Enterprise Administrator tests?  Its been a while since I've taken a MS exam and was just wondering what has helped others study.

Answer (score 3):

I have been working towards my MCITP Enterprise Administrator and have been using the MS training kit books followed by an Exam Cram book with Transcenders for practice testing.  I have been successful on all my exams so far, 3 for 3.

Comment: Well done @Christopher.

Answer (score 2):

The official book does an excellent job of covering the material that's on the test.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend trying out the CBT nuggets videos or TrainSignal videos along with the MS training books.

I prefer the video + books because they provide a lab to follow along with. The downside of the video's are the lack of detail (and price). I have had success reading the pertaining chapter in the book and then watch the video, then follow along with my home lab.

I dislike the brain dump books because when you need to recall that information a year later, chances are you wont recall it. Again this is where the home labs really helped me, the hands on seems to stick with me.

I can *highly* recommend the CBT nuggets videos for CCNA, but I have not tried the MCITP ones yet. Both have sample videos to check out.

Check out Microsofts virtual labs, I haven't used them but they look promising.
[Microsoft Virtual Labs](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/virtual-lab.aspx)

This along with VMware will make it easy to try out server for labs

Answer (score 0):

The exam cram practice tests work for me.  To actually learn the material I use the MS books